# Taxonomy term title as page title in custom view

Tags: views

I have a custom view where I show a list of nodes by taxonomy term. Since there are many terms in dictionary, I can't describe every view page manually. Is there any way to set the page title as a taxonomy term title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the argument added into the filter and there will be option to override the title, there  you can pass %1 which will automatically replace the title with the Taxonomy term title.

[image]

Comment: In my case it prints term id.

Comment: Ok, When I specified validation criteria it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For **Drupal 8** this would be `{{ arguments.name }}`.