# Taxonomy term name in page.html.twig

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

I have a list of taxonomy terms to make some categories on my website. When I click on one of them, the content appears, but I can't display the taxonomy term name. I can't find the right configuration in my view.

> [image]

To display the result, I need to alter the page.html.twig template and the views template. I want to display the name of the term in the page--my_name.html.twig template.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/84266/89581).  The screenshot in the first answer is from D7 but it is very much the same interface in D8.   Just need to change %1 to {{ arguments.tid }} or {{ arguments.name }} as the second answer notes.  You shouldn't need to modify twigs for this, necessarily.

Comment: Than you for your answer, it works ! However i used {{ raw_arguments.term_node_taxonomy_name_depth }}  to find the taxonomy term. after i retrieve it with {{ page['#title'] }} in my template. It comes with dashes, but a filter twig may like replace may fixt that.

Comment: @MaximeIsambert – I think it would be helpful if you add a D8 answer under the existing question.